# Fortran90 Type/rank mismatch in argument

Tags: arrays, fortran90

I'm allocating the dimension of some arrays once I have calculated steps, then I send the allocated arrays to a function but I have the error Type/rank mismatch in argument 'a'.

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

```
 integer i, steps, noutput, savestep

double integrationtime, outputstep, timestep, deltat, ain, ein

real, dimension(:), allocatable :: a, e, time

steps=int(integrationtime/timestep)



 allocate(time(steps), a(steps), e(steps))
  time(0)=0.0d0
 a(0)=ain*1.49597870691d11
 e(0)=ein



 call calc (steps, a, e, time)



 stop



  contains



  subroutine calc (steps, a, e, time)

  integer i, steps

  double precision time(steps), a(steps), e(steps)


   do i=1, steps
   time(i)=..


     a(i)=...

   e(i)=...


   end subroutine calc
```

I have also tried to declare a , e, and time as real allocatable in the subroutine calc, but I get these errors:
In file tidalevolution.f90:84

real, dimension(:), allocatable :: a, e, time
1
Error: ALLOCATABLE attribute conflicts with DUMMY attribute at (1)
In file tidalevolution.f90:86

allocate(time(steps), a(steps), e(steps))
1
Error: Syntax error in ALLOCATE statement at (1)

Comment: In the main program you're assigning to `time(0)`, `a(0)`, and `e(0)`. In fortran, array indexing starts at 1 by default.

Answer (score 2):

In your main program you've defined `a` (and `e`, and `time`) as single-precision real variables:

```
real, dimension(:), allocatable :: a, e, time
```

But you're passing it to a routine which expects double precision arrays:

```
subroutine calc (steps, a, e, time)

    integer i, steps
    double precision time(steps), a(steps), e(steps)
```